# Lighthouse Pagespeed > HTTP2

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, http2, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I´ve got an issue with my pagespeed performance, I cannot resolve.

When I run Lighthouse from the Chrome Dev Tools, the overall performance is quite ok (not perfect, but ok...).
When I run Lighthouse in a separate Tab or when I use pagespeed insights the performance is terrible.

Main difference: Dev Tools and Lighthouse run from within Dev Tools make use of HTTP/2, while Lighthouse in a separate Tab and Pagespeed insights both use HTTP 1.1 and tell me to activate HTTP/2.

Does anyone have an idea, why it works in Dev Tools, but not when it runs separately?

Comment: care to share a link to your site, this isn't a known bug or issue as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

Difference in score is

1. Not due to docking lighthouse in same screen Or seperate window
2. When you dock in same window the viewport will be less so LCP/CLS calculates only for above fold so you would see better score with docing in same screen since viewport is reduced.
3. When you dock in seperate window the viewport will be more so LCP/CLS calculates for larger viewport so you would see difference in score.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I´m not wondering why the result is different. I don´t understand why it uses http/2 in dev tools, but tells me to activate http/2 when executed separately.

Comment: Hi Stefan,  I tried website that has http2 enabled as well as disabled. Lighthouse in Dev Tools on both conditions Docked to same window Or New tab returning right results to me.